# How to Find All .tex Files in Directories in Recurse Grep?

Tags: grep, find, symlink

I want to expand the recursive search of symlinks to include only .tex files `find . -type l -name "Math*" -exec grep -d "recurse" word {} +`. Failed pseudocode 1

```
find . -type l -name "Math*" \
  -exec WHERE CHOOSE ONLY .tex files and Directories \
  -exec grep -d "recurse" word {} +
```

I cannot type a command for choosing .tex files and directories. 
In words, pseudocode 2

1. Find all symlinks with name "Math" which point to directories.
2. Recurse all symlinked directories (I think grep is limiting here possibly)
3. Do basic `grep word` in file list

How can you do the step (2)?

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but what's "sequ"?

Comment: @Kusalananda It is just a word to be searched. Thank you for pointing it out! I made it clearer.

Comment: So you have a bunch of symlinks called "Math*", and they point to LaTeX/TeX documents that you'd like to search for the string "sequ"? Or they point to directories with documents?

Comment: @Kusalananda Symlinks point to directories which have other directories. End things are .tex files.

Comment: Don't have time for a proper answer right now, but something along the lines of `basename $(readlink '{}')` should be your friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this must be one of the silliest command piplines I ever have concocted:

```
$ find . -type l -name "Math*" -print0 |
  xargs -0 -n 1 -IXXX find XXX/ -type f -name "*.tex" -print0 |
  xargs -0 fgrep "word"
```

1. Find all symbolic links called `Math*`.
2. Do `find` again on each found path, looking for `*.tex` files. The `xargs` need to use `-n 1` to call `find` with no more than one pathname. The pathname will be put into the `XXX` placeholder.
3. Call `fgrep` (i.e. `grep -F` since we have a fixed search string) with the string on found files.

Comment: Can you compare it to Michael's proposal about `basename $(readlink) '{}')`? Do you understand his point?

Comment: @Masi I'm wondering if that helps or not, actually. Well, possibly if you want to try to do it in a shorter pipeline, but my brain just started leaking after calling `find` from `xargs` so I can't think properly right now...

Comment: @Masi, yes, `-n 1`, because I need to give exactly *one* path for to each of the `find`.  I also need the `/` after `XXX` to be sure the Math symlink is followed. You can probably use a flag or other for that instead, but it was a cheap solution.

Comment: Some formal people may certainly tells you that `fgrep` is deprecated. I will not.

Comment: @Emmanuel Those formal people do not know that `fgrep` is not a standard utility, and therefore can't be deprecated ;-)

Comment: @Masi - If you change the first `-print0` for `-exec readilnk -f {} \;` it will then be similar to what Michael Kjörling suggests.  But I do not believe it is needed since there is no real need to *explicitly* resolve the symlinks.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it:

```
find . -type l -name 'Math*' -print0 | \
xargs -0 sh -c \
    'find -L "$@" -type f -name "*.tex" -exec fgrep word /dev/null {} +' sh
```

The `sh -c '...' sh` abomination is necessary to deal with the case when `Math*` can have spaces.  Otherwise, when `Math*` **doesn't expand to filenames with spaces**, something like this would work:

```
find -L $(find . -type l -name 'Math*') -name '*.tex' \
    -exec fgrep word /dev/null {} +
```

The `/dev/null` makes sure `fgrep` prints a filename even when it only has a single file to search.

If you insist on the resolving links before grepping, it can be done too, at the price of making the assumptions that (1) your filenames don't contain newlines, and (2) you're using `xargs` from GNU `findutils` (BSD `xargs` doesn't accept `-d`):

```
find . -type l -name 'Math*' -exec readlink -f {} + | \
xargs -d '\n' sh -c \
    'find "$@" -type f -name "*.tex" -exec fgrep word /dev/null {} +' sh
```

Comment: Your second command. Your `find . -type l -name 'Math*` gives relative paths etc `./Mathematics`. Your `find -L $(find . -type l -name 'Math*') -name '*.tex'` gives `find: ‘./Mathematics’: No such file or directory`. I think it is because the first command is giving a relative path.

Comment: @Masi Did you read the paragraph before that?  It explains why the (simpler) second command doesn't work, and why you actually need the first one, or the last.  You just re-discovered that out on your own.

Comment: I am considering how to trim long one-liners of the content here http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/293207/16920

Comment: @Masi Pipe the result to something like `cut -c -80`.

Comment: Then you have a broken `cut`, that doesn't deal well with locales. _shrug_