# How to Limit ContentMatches of Grep in List?

Tags: grep, find

I know the thread [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/175852/what-commands-will-feed-a-tab-delimited-text-file-and-cut-each-line-to-80-char) which proposals (`... | cut -c 80`) however give single letter outputs like `n r s t p`. I do

```
# https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/293147/16920
find -L $(find . -type l -name 'Math*') -name '*.tex' -exec fgrep word /dev/null {} +
```

Some matches have too much content which I would like to cut; most other matches are ok but long-one liners are a problem in contents

```
...
/Math/16.5.2014.tex:Feedback Control of Hormone SecrAlthough the plasma concentrations of many hormones fluctuate in response to various stimuli that occur throughout the day, all hormones studied thus far appear to be closely controlled. In most instances, word [lot more]
...
```

Comment: @SatoKatsura Actually, I like a lot more your proposal than `expand` and `cut`.

Comment: There are a few commands that are written for this kind of massaging: `cut`, `col`, `pr`, `fmt` (maybe others).  `sed`, `awk`, `perl` etc. are higher level, and a lot more complicated.

Comment: @SatoKatsura Yes, do you understand the reason for single-letter output with `... | cut -c 80`? I think the problem in combining `expand` into it or no tab-delimitation here.

Comment: It should be `cut -c -80`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do piping of the result [Sato]

```
find | 
| cut -c -80
```

or

```
find ... \
| sed 's/^\(.\{80\}\).*/\1/'
```

or

```
find - \
| perl -lpe 's/^.{80}\K.*//'
```

which give correct outputs.