# How to Avoid Many Levels of symlinks with this find?

Tags: find, symlink

I know the [thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/141442/16920) and try to fix my find with `-mindepth 15` unsuccessfully

```
find -L $HOME -type f -name "*.tex" \
   -exec fgrep -l "janne" /dev/null {} + | vim -R -
```

Unsuccessful attempt

```
find -L $HOME -type f -mindepth 15 -name "*.tex" \
   -exec fgrep -l "janne" /dev/null {} + | vim -R -
```

- `find -L` about it [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/293147/16920)

Its STOUT

```
Vim: Reading from stdin...
find: ‘/home/masi/LOREM’: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

Visualization of symlinks unsuccessful which gives all files while I would like to see only symlinked directories and files in the system

```
tree -l
```

### Law29's proposal

```
# include symlinks
find "$1" -type l -name "$2*" -print0 \
    | xargs -0 grep -Hr --include "*.tex" "$2" /dev/null {} + | vim -R -
```

Output unsuccessful but it should not be empty

```
Vim: Reading from stdin...
grep: {}: No such file or directory
grep: +: No such file or directory
```

Characteristics of the system

```
masi@masi:~$ ls -ld -- "$HOME" /home/masi/LOREM 
drwxr-xr-x 52 masi masi 4096 Aug 16 16:09 /home/masi
lrwxrwxrwx  1 masi masi   17 Jun 20 00:27 /home/masi/LOREM -> /home/masi/LOREM/

masi@masi:~$ type find
find is /usr/bin/find

masi@masi:~$ find --version
find (GNU findutils) 4.7.0-git
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Eric B. Decker, James Youngman, and Kevin Dalley.
Features enabled: D_TYPE O_NOFOLLOW(enabled) LEAF_OPTIMISATION FTS(FTS_CWDFD) CBO(level=2)
```

System: Linux Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit
For for Script at the thread: [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/789769/25388)
Find: 4.7.0
Grep: 2.25
Application of `find`: `haetex` [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/789769/25388)

Comment: Why are you using -L? Can you not just do the find from the lowest common directory?

Comment: @Law29 Please, see the answer http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/293147/16920 why I am using `find -L`.

Comment: Why do you have `/home/masi/LOREM` as a symlink to itself? You will get the error "Too many levels of symbolic links" from any utility that attempts to dereference this circular link.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still not sure I understand what it is that you're trying to do. Is it to edit all tex files that contain the text "janne", including those referenced via symlinks? If so, what's wrong with your original `find -L "$HOME" -type f -name '*.tex' -exec grep -l 'janne' {} + | vim -R -`? Furthermore you say in your question that « _I would like to see only symlinked directories and files in the system_ ». Why not `find -L "$HOME" -xtype l`? Either way, you cannot avoid the "Too many levels of symbolic links" error unless you redirect _stderr_ to `/dev/null`

Comment: If you want to follow symbolic links with `-L` then you *will* get the error message, "Too many levels of symbolic links". If you don't want to follow the broken symbolic link (i.e. you use `-H` or nothing at all) then you won't get the error.

Comment: @roaima I want to follow unbroken symlinks, not broken ones and not infinity loops.

Comment: `find` won't follow infinite loops - it keeps track of the places it's already visited and won't use them a second time around. If you want to follow symlinks then you *will* get errors from entries like the one you've created with your `LOREM` file. The only way to avoid those is to redirect _stderr_ away from the terminal (for example to `/dev/null`). Or to change the source code for `find` and have it not print the corresponding error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display all files under `$HOME`, including those referenced via symbolic links, that end with `.tex` and contain the string `janne`:

```
find -L "$HOME" -type f -name '*.tex' -exec grep -l 'janne' {} + 2>/dev/null | vim -R -
```

If you want to display only symbolic links found under `$HOME` named `*.tex` corresponding to files that contain the string `janne`:

```
find -L "$HOME" -xtype l -name '*.tex' -exec grep -l 'janne' {} + 2>/dev/null | vim -R -
```

The only way to avoid the error message "Too many levels of symbolic links" is to discard all errors, which I've done with the `2>/dev/null` construct.

In both cases the `find` verb will not traverse across files and directories that it has already traversed - it remembers where it's already visited and prunes those parts of the filesystem tree automatically. For example,

```
mkdir a a/b a/b/c
cd a/b/c
ln -s ../../../a

# Here you can ls a/b/c/a/b/c/a/b/...

# But find will not continue for very long
find -L a
a
a/b
a/b/c
find: File system loop detected; ‘a/b/c/a’ is part of the same file system loop as ‘a’.
```

Comment: @Masi - no... he offers you solutions that don't use the `-L` flag on `find`.

Comment: @Masi that's right, it isn't. I'm using `/dev/null` in a different way for a different purpose, though. And I'm offering you your `-L` flag.

Comment: @Masi `-L` follows all symlinks. `-H` only follows those at the top level. I used `grep` rather than `fgrep` because it doesn't matter in this instance. You could use `fgrep` if you preferred.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you have recursive symlinks. I would consider two options:

- forget about the `-L`, get all the files named .tex anywhere in the tree, and then filter them (is there no other criteria than being in a directory that is pointed to by a symlink that starts with "Math"?)
- Do it in two steps, both without `-L`: first you search for all symlinks named "Math*" (and maybe directories too?). You take that list and search for your tex files recursively from there, like this:

  ```
  find . -type l -name "Math*" -print0 \    
      | xargs -0 grep -Hr --include "*.tex" "janne"
  ```

Comment: Yes that's what it's supposed to do. I really do not understand why you have such a symlink structure though, nor why you have to respect it, not the why of this search. I would do a `grep -r` of the whole file-system if need be, and then manually look through the files I found.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your problem at several levels. I hope someone else will be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

If the reason you're using `-L` is because `$HOME` is a symlink and you still want `find` to descend into it (but not in the other symlink to directories which would cause the problem you're running into), then use:

```
find "$HOME/" -name '*.tex' -type f -exec fgrep -l janne {} +
```

(`/dev/null` not needed with `-l`).

Or:

```
find -H "$HOME" -name '*.tex' -type f -exec fgrep -l janne {} +
```

That looks inside *regular* files only as generally, you don't want to look inside fifos, devices or directories. To also look inside symlinks to regular files (but then you'd be likely looking into the same file several times), you can change the `-type f` to `-xtype f` (assuming GNU `find`).

Comment: @Masi, what does `ls -ld -- "$HOME" /home/masi/LOREN` output?

Comment: @Masi, I can't reproduce your problem with `find -H /home/masi -exec fgrep -l {} +` with the same versions of those utilities. I can only reproduce it with `find -H /home/masi/LOREM -exec fgrep -l {}` as then we're explicitely asking `find` to resolve that broken symlink, which it can't do.

Comment: @Masi, but without `-L`, with `find /home/masi`, `find` will have no reason to resolve the LOREM symlink, so can't output that message. Without the  `-name '*.tex'`, or `-type f`, `fgrep` could complain about it, but not `find`, so I'm confused by your error message. Do you have an alias for `find`? What does `type find` tell you?

Comment: You are right! I went all my codes through again in a clean system. I also added my system info about `find` in the body. This command `find -H "$1" -xtype f -name "*.tex" -exec fgrep -l $case_option "$2" {} +` works and solves the case, passing also my test. - - Please, state any limitations etc about it.