# Why this find -L ... fgrep fails?

Tags: grep, find

I moved away from Ubuntu to Debian, and having a problem with my `find` now for searching tex files for the word *masi*. 
Code and its output

```
masi@masi:~$ find -L "/home/masi/" -xtype f \
    -name "*.tex" -exec fgrep -l 'masi' {} + /dev/null

find: paths must precede expression: /dev/null
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
```

- `/dev/null` is necessary in the second command set because we are using `find -L`, since we want to include all symlinks and go them through and not exclude anything in the search. Thread where the motivation for the use [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/304027/16920) about *How to Avoid Many Levels of symlinks with this find?*

As one-liner

```
find -L "/home/masi/" -xtype f -name "*.tex" -exec fgrep -l 'masi' {} + /dev/null
```

OS: Debian 8.5
Linux kernel: 4.6 of backports
Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UA
Related: `find` command of my `haetex` script in the thread [How to search .tex files?](https://askubuntu.com/a/789769/25388)
Find: `find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2`
Fgrep: `grep (GNU grep) 2.20`

Comment: What exactly is that `/dev/null` in the end supposed to mean?

Comment: Also, your `fgrep` invocation is missing the search string. Should be something like `fgrep -l 'some string' {} +`. I can't understand what the `/dev/null` is supposed to do here.

Comment: @ByteCommander I adedd an explanation for that.

Comment: @Munir Yes, mistake in writing the code here again, fixed.

Comment: It must be `2>/dev/null` in the end to hide stderr messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just:

```
find -L /home/masi/ -xtype f -name "*.tex" -exec fgrep -l 'masi' {} +
```

no need `/dev/null` as far as `{}` is the place holder for the processed file(s)

If you try to hide the error output, use it like this :

```
command 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: In my case, there is a need of `/dev/null` but change it only to `2>/dev/null`.

Comment: I just try to guess your misstake ;)